# How speed up loading nginx in Windows Docker?

Tags: php, docker, performance, nginx

Container images:  "nginx", "php:7.4-fpm" (memory_limit = 1024M), "mysql:8.0.23".
My PC: i7-2600, 16GB, SSD.
Loading pages is wildly slow. How can I speed up loading?

Comment: You should also search on google, I am sure you will find a solution like this - https://www.nginx.com/blog/10-tips-for-10x-application-performance/

Comment: as said above you have to make better your searching on stackoverflow and other engines

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/) you should check the docs:

> Share only the directories that you need with the container. File sharing introduces overhead as any changes to the files on the host need to be notified to the Linux VM. Sharing too many files can lead to high CPU load and slow filesystem performance.

> Shared folders are designed to allow application code to be edited on the host while being executed in containers. For non-code items such as cache directories or databases, the performance will be much better if they are stored in the Linux VM, using a data volume (named volume) or data container.

Comment: db in container, php scripts not in container

Comment: Where are your nginx or php pages?

Comment: php scripts not in container - they mapped as volumes

Comment: You should try to create a "named volume" and add the php scripts there. If you are using WSL2 then you can access the named volume filesystems in this path: `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\.. `. You'll find a folder for each named volume there, add your files under the `_data` folder.